# PHP array in if else

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I'm still in my PHP basic training, but I want to show multiple meta_boxes when a post is 'specialisaties'. I'm loading 1 meta box, but I need to add another one called 'url, $meta_boxes = url_post_meta_boxes();

```
} else if ($post->post_type == 'specialisaties') {
    $meta_boxes = specialisaties_post_meta_boxes();
}
```

How do I change the else if to load multiple $meta_boxes?

Comment: `$meta_boxes = [specialisaties_post_meta_boxes(), url_post_meta_boxes()];`?

Comment: So you want both in one $meta_boxes variable?

Comment: What @Phil said. `$meta_boxes` will become an array, and you will need to use it as such.

Comment: this question makes no sense https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: is this WP or some blog engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn it into an array by this way:

```
} else if ($post->post_type == 'specialisaties') {
    $meta_boxes = [specialisaties_post_meta_boxes(), url_post_meta_boxes()];
}
```